# How to implement a WebSocket with Retrofit + RX

Tags: android, websocket, retrofit, rx-android

I have a project structure that uses Retrofit with Rx.

I would like to use it to implement also WebSocket communication, any idea how i can accomplish that?

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain me what is RX?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Retrofit doesn't support web sockets yet. The feature is anticipated to be in the `2.1` release. However, there's a branch that JW has been working on. You can build Retrofit from [his branch](https://github.com/square/retrofit/compare/jw/websocket) and try it. Or can wait till the 2.1 release. This is the corresponding [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/924) on Github.

Comment: Do you have some update with the Retrofit 2.1 released?

Comment: @paulokhouri check the project page on GitHub, I don't see any classes related to web sockets in the 2.1 release.

Comment: (Since then, they rescheduled it for 2.2)